# Tesseract OCR crash when used in thread

Tags: ocr, tesseract

i got a strange probem with tesseract ocr. everything works fine, like the ocr part. characters are recognized correctly. but it crashes after it has done all calculations
this only happens when i run the code in a thread.

```
void server(boost::asio::io_service & io_service, unsigned short port)
    {

        tcp::acceptor a(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
        for (;;)
        {

            a.accept(sock);

            //boost::thread t(session, boost::ref(sock));
            //t.detach();
            std::thread(session, std::move(sock)).detach();
        }
    }

void session(tcp::socket & sock)
{
        tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
        if (api.Init("", "eng"))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
        {
            if (!sudokuDatainside[i].empty())
            {
                api.SetImage((uchar*)sudokuDatainside[i].data, sudokuDatainside[i].size().width, sudokuDatainside[i].size().height, sudokuDatainside[i].channels(), sudokuDatainside[i].step1());
                // Get OCR result

                outText = api.GetUTF8Text();
                std::cout << outText << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Nothing - " << i << std::endl;
            }
        }
        api.End();
}
```

Edit: seems its not a problem with api.End(). even if i dont call this method the programm crashes when the thread ends... does tesseract support threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of trying to find a solution. I came across an error during building the debug libs. 
So rebuilding the tesseract debug libs solved the problem.
Here are the instructions i used:
https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-vs2012